# Fail to retrieve info through SMBus to Atmel chip

Tags: smbus

This is my setup, Atmel chip (**SAMD20E18A-MUT**) SM bus two pins connected to Host PC via SMBus/USB adapter chip **CP2112**).

On host side, managed to scan the SMBus (6) through i2c-tools and see the Atmel device at slave address 0x6a.

send 1 byte data to device $sudo i2cset -y 6 0x6a 0x00 0x00

retrieve 9 bytes of data sudo i2cdump -y -r 0x00-0x08 6 0x6a

it return all zero, expecting to get some data. My question is what should be my "DATA-ADDRESS" in i2cset, currently i'm using 0x00. I look at the Atmel data sheet, but can't figure out what would be the correct address. Is there anything that i should check?

Note: Other people managed to get non-zero response on the SAME device but they are using commercial Ginkgo SMBUs/USB adapter. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After chat with device supplier, the requirement is to send one byte to device (without Command code) and read back the specified number of bytes (without Command code).

$sudo i2cset -y 6 0x6a 0x00 #SMBus=6, Device add=0x6a

$sudo i2cget -y 6 0x6a 0x00 c #expected "single byte" data is returned

My question is, does i2c-tool support to read back the specified amount of return data or any other tool support it? From my understanding looking at the SMBus spec, this kind of read back cmd protocol not supported (not part of 15x supported protocols).